# Is the category of sets a model of category theory?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, foundations

I think usually a model of a theory is a translation to a set ( for example, models of group theory are structured sets like $(\mathbb{R}, +)$, $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$,… etc.). But a collection of all sets, or the type Set, is not a set. Is the category of sets a model of category theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion in terminology here.
I would not call a group a "model of group theory".
It is a "model of the (first order) theory of groups".
On the other hand, the universe of all sets is a model of set theory, modulo some issues about size and expressive power.
The category of all sets is, modulo the same issues, a category in particular and is a model of the (first order) theory of categories.
But I would definitely not say it is a "model of category theory".
That should be reserved for the 2-category of all categories.

Comment: But is a model category a model of category theory, and is the category of sets a model of model category theory?

Comment: A model category is a model of ... homotopy theory. Terminology is difficult.